# How to make a "did you mean" link with suggestions, in google maps api?

Tags: javascript, maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to make a web application with google maps api, that gives directions. Right now, It gives directions fine unless the user types in something wrong, it either doesn't show anything or it tries to figure it out and gives the wrong address. I want to make functionality where if the address is not recognized it has "did you mean" and then make a suggestion that's close to what you were trying to enter. I couldn't find anything in the google code that talked about that, but I'm wondering if anyone knows if it's possible, and how I can do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loadFromWayPoints() draws polyline only if the inputs provided to it maps to any definite point on the earth. You can avoid the confusion to function by fixing your from point in form of latitude and longitude, instead of address. Then using following function you may create Did you mean for To point if multiple points returned for toInput.

Code is self explanatory. If you dont understand. Reply in comment.
One of the point you want to plot should return definite point from google geocoder system.
In my I used the from point as definite point. And had it coordinates with me. So there is no chance of getting

```
geo.getLocations(toInput, function (result){
        //map.clearOverlays();
        if (result.Status.code == G_GEO_SUCCESS) {
            // ===== If there was more than one result, "ask did you mean" on them all =====
            if (result.Placemark.length > 1) {
                document.getElementById("textualdirectionscontainer").innerHTML = "Did you mean:";
                // Loop through the results
                for (var i=0; i<result.Placemark.length; i++) {
                    var p = result.Placemark[i].Point.coordinates;
                    document.getElementById("textualdirectionscontainer").innerHTML += "<br>"+(i+1)+": <a href='javascript:place(" +p[1]+","+p[0]+")'>"+ result.Placemark[i].address+"<\/a>";
                }
            }
            // ===== If there was a single marker =====
            else {
                document.getElementById("textualdirectionscontainer").innerHTML = "";
                var p = result.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates;
                toLatLang = new GLatLng(p[1], p[0]);
    //          place(p[1],p[0]);
                directionsPanel = $('textualdirectionscontainer');
                directionsPanel.getElements('div').each(function(item) {
                    item.dispose();
                });
                directions.clear(); 
                directions.loadFromWaypoints([hotelLatLng.toString(), toLatLang.toString()], {getPolyline:true});
                /*var gp = directions.getPolyline();
                map.addOverlay(gp); */
            } 
        }
    });
```